# Как работает сборщик мусора с неуправляемыми типами

Tags: c#, типы-данных, сборщик-мусора

Знаю что сборщик мусора очищает только управляемые типы в управляемой куче. Для неуправляемых есть интерфейс IDisposable. Но всегда считал что неуправляемые типы это например потоки, соединения с бд и т.п. Но в документации microsoft сказано что неуправляемыми типами являются следующие:

```
sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal или bool.
```

Типы хранящие свои значения в стеке. Всегда почему то думал что они тоже должны собираться сборщиком мусора. Подскажите пожалуйста они действительно собираются сборщиком мусора или их нужно самому как то очищать из памяти? Вот ссылка на ресурс где говорится что эти типы являются неуправляемыми.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types

Update:
Приведите пожалуйста примеры управляемых и неуправляемых ресурсов для которых нужно использовать IDisposable?

Comment: Все что в стеке, очищать не надо. Как только происходит выход из функции, которая брала что то в стеке, она эту область освобождает сама, без всякого сборщика мусора

Comment: Вы путаете неуправляемые типы с [неуправляемыми ресурсами](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged).

Comment: Всё освобождение стека сводится к сдвигу указателя на вершину назад

Comment: @АндрейNOP немного не понял что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @Mike а если не в какую функцию переменные не передаются? А используются там где объявлены? Когда они будут очищены? Как и написано о сборщике мусора, как только переполнится пороговое значение выделяемое под поколение 0?

Comment: передача тут не причем. переменные объявлены внутри функции, вот пока она выполняется, переменные ей нужны и они есть в стеке. Когда она завершиться, стек освободится. И сборщик мусора тут вообще не причем, он нужен что бы очищать кучу. Стек сам по себе.

Comment: @Mike а теперь понял. То есть они перестают существовать как только отработает тот метод где они объявлены. Например тот же page_load

Comment: Да. при входе в метод указатель вершины стека перемещается "вперед" на столько, сколько занимают все локальные переменные. при обращении к переменным происходит обращение по заложенному компилятором смещению относительно вершины (назад). при выходе из метода указатель вершины возвращается назад, таким образом вся область памяти, которую занимали локальные переменные оказывается свободна

Comment: @Mike большое спасибо